# Space inside the button control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have button according to language selection
Ex:English1
[image]

Portugese

[image]

i need to show space in left and right side of the content in button?

This is my xaml code

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="6"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                             <Button Style="{StaticResource LoginButtonStyle}" Margin="10,0,15,20" Content="{x:Static strings:Resources.Login}" Command="{Binding LoginCmd}" 
                                IsDefault="True" MinWidth="90" Padding="5,5,5,5"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding LoginEnabled,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </StackPanel>
```

Please check this is my code snippet.Inside grid row 6 i added stackpanel for button

```
<Border BorderThickness=".5" Width="449.629" Height="570" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding}"></ContentPresenter>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.STR_USER_NAME}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" Margin="40,17,20,0"/>
                        <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="Login_UserName" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MaxHeight="100" WatermarkContent="Enter User Name" Margin="0,15,30,15" MaxLength="20"
                        Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Background="#FFE6E6E6" Foreground="#FF666666" 
                                                 Width="205" Style="{StaticResource TextBox_ValidationTemplate}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}" FontSize="15" Height="25" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" LostFocus="Login_UserName_LostFocus">
                            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" FontStyle="Normal" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.STR_PASSWORD}"  Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" Margin="40,5,20,0"/>
                        <PasswordBox x:Name="Login_Password" BorderThickness="0" MaxLength="20" Height="25" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="#FFE6E6E6" Foreground="#FF666666" 
                                 FontSize="15" FontStyle="Normal" IsEnabled="{Binding NewMode}" 
                                 common:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="205" Margin="00,0,30,15"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"
            common:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password,Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" LostFocus="Login_Password_LostFocus">
                        </PasswordBox>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.SERVER_NAME}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" Margin="40,5,20,0"/>

                        <telerik:RadComboBox Style="{StaticResource RadComboBoxStyle}" Margin="00,0,30,15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerNameColl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    Width="205" Height="25" Text="{Binding SelectedServerName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></telerik:RadComboBox>

                    </Grid>




                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,0,30,5"  >
                            <TextBlock   Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.SERVER_IP}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ServerIP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" FontStyle="Italic" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Margin="40,0,10,20"  >
                            <TextBlock>
                            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ServerSettingsCmd}" Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}">
                                <Run Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.SERVER_SETTINGS}"/>
                            </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding ErrorMsg, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxHeight="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" Margin="40,7,30,0" Content="{x:Static strings:Resources.REMEMBERME}" IsChecked="{Binding RememberMe}" MinWidth="150"  />
                        <TextBlock Padding="7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ForgotPwdCmd}" Style="{StaticResource HyperLinkStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}"  >
                    <Run Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.FORGOTPWD}"/>
                </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>

                    </Grid>

                    <!--<StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="40,0,0,10" >


                    </StackPanel>-->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="6"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource GrayButtonStyle}" Margin="5,0,15,20" Content="{x:Static strings:Resources.CANCEL}" IsCancel="True" MinWidth="90"/>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource LoginButtonStyle}" Margin="10,0,15,20" Content="{x:Static strings:Resources.Login}" Command="{Binding LoginCmd}" 
                                IsDefault="True" MinWidth="90" Padding="5,5,5,5"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding LoginEnabled,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" X1="0" X2="449.629" ></Line>
                        <Grid Margin="40,0,0,0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,10,5,0"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                       Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.STR_SOFTWARE_VERSION}"></TextBlock>

                            <TextBlock Margin="5,10,5,2"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book14pt}" 
                                       Text="{Binding AssemblyVersion}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,2,5,0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book15pt}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                       Text="{x:Static strings:Resources.STR_SW_SERIALNO}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,2"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle-CentraleSansCnd-Book14pt}" 
                                       Text="{Binding SerialNumber}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

This is for style

```
<Style x:Key="LoginButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="200" />
        <!--<Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />-->
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"></Setter>       
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Style="{StaticResource CentraleSansCnd-Book17pt}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>                       
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="1" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding LoginEnabled,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9741D1"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF5F0099"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="2" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding LoginEnabled,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF209E8C"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF005D4F"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="3" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding LoginEnabled,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0074DF"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0046A8"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="4" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding LoginEnabled,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF7AAD00"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF437800"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="5" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding LoginEnabled,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF9D2A"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC96800"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>    


            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="3" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3FA7EF"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF005D4F"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="1" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD177FF"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF9741D1"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="2" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF60D5C1"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF209E8C"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="4" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFB2E44C"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF7AAD00"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding App}" Value="5" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFB847"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFE98300"></Setter>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Style for CentraleSansCnd-Book17pt

```
<Style x:Key="CentraleSansCnd-Book17pt">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#CentraleSansCnd-Book" />
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="17" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Please post your code / xaml - have you set padding ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the xaml rather than adding it as a comment

Comment: Your button is most likely sized by the container. Please include it in your XAML snippet

Comment: Inside the stackpanel i added my button

Comment: @Shri - could you also include the `Grid` that your `StackPanel` is nested inside, please? It could be that the grid's column width might be restricting it? It is a bit unclear unless you can add all the relevant parent/children - thank you :)

Comment: I have added full code please help me to solve this

Comment: Grid row 6 only height i mentioned auto.

Comment: Does the text appear like that when you run the app or in the designer also ? How does it appear when you hard code the phrase 'Efetuar logon' ? I've taken your xaml and used it in a test app (minus the styles and telerik controls) and it comes out fine btw

Comment: in designer it will show in english. once am change the language(english to Portuguese) in run time it will show as per mention in the Portuguese image

Comment: What happens if you don't apply the LoginButtonStyle style - does the text appear with the correct spacing ?

Comment: Yes if i remove the style it will show properly with padding

Comment: I have added login button style also

Comment: let me know what is the wrong in the styles.It is not allowing padding when  i added style in button xaml

Comment: In your `LoginButtonStyle`, style the setter `<Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="200" />` is limiting the button to 200px maximum. Try removing this and see it has any effect.

Comment: I've a hunch its something to do with `CentraleSansCnd-Book17pt` style - please post this also

Comment: Good shout, @auburg - I'll second that

Comment: @auburg i have added  CentraleSansCnd-Book17pt style

Comment: @Geoff James i have removed  <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="200" /> .But didn't find any effect in button

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have the CentraleSansCnd-Book font that you're using - does not using that font remove the problem ? In my test app that uses your xaml (without the Telerik controls) i don't have the spacing issue . Also, if you hard code the text 'Efetuar logon' as the button content does the problem still occur ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,I got the answer.
inside the style there is one template.Here in Border tag i added padding property.Its solved my problem

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="10,0,10,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Style="{StaticResource CentraleSansCnd-Book17pt}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Thanks all

Comment: Glad you got there, in the end. However I don't think any of us stood a chance of finding that - as it wasn't in your code in the OP! So much Xaml!

Answer (score -1):

Add "Margin" on your button style.

```
<Style x:Key="LoginButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? There is already margin on the `Button` element, as per the OP - *plus* margin is **outside** of the button, and will not affect the text **inside**... For that you would need to adjust padding - which is what is being discussed in comments